# How do I implement firebase's Timestamp as a valid type?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

ts/ io-ts and am trying to implement Firebase.Timestamp as a valid type. But I keep getting errors. I can create a normal copy of the time stamp:

```
copyTimeStamp = {
  seconds : t.number,
  nanoseconds : t.number
}
```

but if I push that onto firebase using the custom encoded type from io-ts, it isn't stored as Timestamp property rather its just a plain map..

Comment: You should be able to type it to `firebase.firestore.Timestamp`. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Edric , I am trying to make io-ts accept a thrid party type/object but it wouldn't accept them and when I try to simulate the type it gets stored into firebase as a map instead..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `FirebaseFirestoreTypes` from `@react-native-firebase/firestore`.

Here it is:

```
import {FirebaseFirestoreTypes} from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

...

type StateTypes = {
  created_at: FirebaseFirestoreTypes.Timestamp | null;
  updated_at: FirebaseFirestoreTypes.Timestamp | null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a timestamp type field in Firestore, you must use either the native JavaScript Date object, or the Timestamp object provided by the Firestore SDK.  You can't simulate it using your own object.

Comment: I am trying to be typesafe from clients potentially entering bad infomration by using fp-ts. And timestamp is doable, as I just parse it with some extra backedn work but with GeoPoint, its a entirely different story because it has N E W S. =/

Comment: You can create your own type for clients of your api, but you must convert that data to one of the objects that Firestone understand when you need to write it.

Comment: hmmm. yah maybe i'll do that, generate the custom type client side and send it to server, if it's invalid then reject it, otherwise proceed to convert the data..

Answer (score 1):

you can create an io-ts codec for a Firebase Timestamp

```
import { Timestamp } from '@firebase/firestore-types';
import * as t from 'io-ts';
```

Define a custom codec for the Timestamp:

```
const FirebaseTimestamp = new t.Type<Timestamp, { seconds: number; nanoseconds: number }, unknown>(
  'FirebaseTimestamp',
  
  // `is` checks if the input value is a Timestamp.
  (input): input is Timestamp => input instanceof Timestamp,
  
  // `validate` converts the input value to a Timestamp if possible.
  (input, context) => {
    if (input instanceof Timestamp) {
      return t.success(input);
    }
    if (typeof input === 'object' && typeof input.seconds === 'number' && typeof input.nanoseconds === 'number') {
      return t.success(new Timestamp(input.seconds, input.nanoseconds));
    }
    return t.failure(input, context);
  },
  
  // `encode` converts a Timestamp back to a plain object.
  (timestamp) => ({
    seconds: timestamp.seconds,
    nanoseconds: timestamp.nanoseconds
  })
);
```